# Hierarchy recordset in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can I get **hierarchy recordset** in ms access through **select** statement?

Comment: Ack! I wish I could click the "offensive" link. :-P Take it from an old dinosaur. Just don't do it. Hierarchical databases always cause more trouble than they solve.

Comment: You can do so by opening the proper ADO connection (with MSDataShape) to your data but what for? There is no way to display such a hierarchy within Access forms, like treeview or similar. Instead of this, Access proposes a form-subform hierarchy that can do the job without hierarchy recordset!

Answer (score 1):

DAO doesn't support Hierarchical recordsets. You may be able to use ADO in access, but I'm not certain.

Comment: You can use ADO in access by adding a reference to the ADO library through the visual basic for applications editor.

Answer (score 1):

ADO 2.0 support MSDataShape - an OLEDB provider.

Check out data shaping at http://microsoft.apress.com/asptodayarchive/72268/data-shaping-with-ado-part-1